# Call back from a HTML/jQuery page from a HTML iFrame or any HTML page

Tags: jquery, html, iframe, callback

So I have a HTML iFrame which makes a call to a page on a server which is HTML/jQuery and this page on the server runs for about 30seconds. There are some timers in the page on the server which are written in jQuery. Once the timers are done, I need to notify the client code which is an iFrame (this can change if needed) and also possible pass some data back. Can this be done? if yes, how?

My HTML code is as follows

```
<iframe id="ifrm" name="ifrm" src="http://somefile.html" scrolling="no" width="100%" height="20%"         align="bottom" frameborder="0" 
    style="position:absolute;Left:15;bottom:-10">
```

somefile.html has a jQuery script file code.js which was some timer code on page load

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  registerImpression();
  setTimeout(
   function(){
        Animate2id('#c2','easeOutQuint');
   },
   10000
);
```

After this 10 second timeout is complete, I want to make a call back to the calling iframe (maybe I need to use some kind of js here to listen to the calls) and then do some action after 10 seconds.

Comment: Please post some code samples so we can better help and understand the situation.

Answer (score 0):

you can't access iframe page, if the page is in different domain that yours

Comment: It doesn't even have to be an iFrame, i'm just trying to see if maybe having some client side JS embed the code on the server can talk back and forth and then change the iFrame size or something like that.